# How to successfully decode ffmpeg frames with http timeouts without parsers

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

I'm facing a scenario where connectivity issues cause ffmpeg generate false / messed artifacts(frames) contrary to what the manual states.

We use `curl` as our http transmitting library and `ffmpeg` as the processing library. To simulate network timeouts, I place several breakpoints in the `AVIOContext` which is passed to the `AVFormatContext`

```
avformat_open_input('http://some.com/1.ts')
while(!eof)
  av_read_frame
  av_send_packet
  while(!av_receive_frame)
     do_something
close
```

`av_receive_frame` should either return `0` upon success or error `-35` for cases where additional data is needed.

So after `timeout-ing` the session, `ffmpeg` can still somehow extract (`av_receive_frame`) the first frame even though it hadn't have the chance to download / accumulate enough data.

[image]

My question, without using `parsers` is there a way to validate that the decoder can successfully decode the packet?

"*EDIT*" : i saw that `av_read_frame` use parsing if `AVStream::need_parsing` attribute is anything than `NONE`, any ideas on how setting it up?